# Swift input == nil produces false when input is nil

Tags: swift

I was trying to check if a value was `nil`, but on a very specific scenario it always produce `false`

```
import Foundation

///
struct Person {
    var name: String
    var lastname: String
    var email: String
    var address: String?
    var age: Int
}

var contact = Person(name: "", lastname: "", email: "", address: nil, age: 18)

///

protocol Checker {
    func check(input: Any?) -> Bool
}

struct Rule<Model> {
    var property: PartialKeyPath<Model>
    var checker: Checker
}

///

struct Nullability: Checker {
    func check(input: Any?) -> Bool {
        input == nil
    }
}

Nullability().check(input: contact.address)                     //true, nil indeed
Nullability().check(input: contact[keyPath: \Person.address])   //true, nil indeed

class Test {
    var all: [(keypath: PartialKeyPath<Person>, checker: Checker)]

    init(all: [(keypath: PartialKeyPath<Person>, checker: Checker)]) {
        self.all = all
    }

    func test(model: Person) -> [Bool] {
        all.map { rule in
            let value = model[keyPath: rule.keypath]
            return rule.checker.check(input: value)
        }
    }
}

let t = Test(all: [(\Person.address, Nullability())])
t.test(model: contact)                                         // [false], BUT IT SHOULD BE TRUE
```

Comment: Looking through some similar questions and answer the problem is that you are using optional Any `Any?` which makes things weird, in the failing test the input to the check method is `Optional(nil)` which is not the same as `nil`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're dealing with nested `Optional`s, which can happen sometimes when dealing with `Any` and `Any?` types. One way around this is to flatten the nested `Optional`s to get to the real wrapped value:

```
protocol Flattenable {
    var flattened: Any? { get }
}

extension Optional: Flattenable {
    var flattened: Any? {
        switch self {
        case .some(let x as Flattenable): return x.flattened
        case .some(let x): return x
        case .none: return nil
        }
    }
}

struct Nullability: Checker {
    func check(input: Any?) -> Bool {
        input.flattened == nil
    }
}
```

Source: [This post and thread from the Swift forums.](https://forums.swift.org/t/challenge-flattening-nested-optionals/24083/4)